# How to make while iteration faster?

Tags: python, performance, list

I was playing on an online-judge website, and one of the problems gave me a time-out error which means that my code is running too slow. I know that Python is a slow language in general, but are there any possible ways to improve the speed of the code below?

```
a = input()
cards = []
for num in xrange(1,a+1):
    cards.append(num)
counter = True

while len(cards) > 1:
    if counter:
        del cards[0]
        counter = False
    else:
        cards.append(cards[0])
        del cards[0]
        counter = True

print cards[0]
```

EDITTED

Sorry that it was such a vague question.
So the problem asks the program to print out the very last card remaining after the execution. First, the very first card will be removed, and next, the first card would be sent to the very back of the stack. This process will be repeated until one card is remaining in the stack. The input is the number of cards.

Take for isntance if the input is 6, the output would be 4.

Comment: Rather than just dump your code, could you explain what is it supposed to be doing? And show an example input and the expected output?

Comment: "*I know that Python is a slow language in general"* ... then you "know" incorrectly

Comment: Could you expand on the problem details?

Comment: Have you run your code locally? How long does it take to execute?

Comment: It took a while for number that goes over six-digits. The problem is there is a card stack and I am to print out the last card remaining after removing first one, and then putting the first card to the very back of the stack, and repeating.

Comment: I guess, if the site automatically checks your program, the problem is `input()`, waiting for user input. Who passes the input value and how?

Comment: The site uses input() to insert the testcases. But still thanks!

Comment: @Cyber Sorry, but the [reference implementation](http://www.python.org/) of Python **is** slow. I love Python, I have used it since version 2.1, I know there are many way to cope with it, and certainly there are external libraries to help things go faster (like numpy). But it's still true that Python **is** slow. On some tests, twice slower than VBA, and much more slower than Lisp. But it's not an insult, you know. Just a fact that is worth knowing. And there are more important things than speed: ease (and speed!) of development, readability, maintainability...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, your code does not meet the requirements as you delete twice when flag is set from `False` to `True`

Comment: @ReutSharabani Not my code. Not my question either :-)

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar your code is not fitting the description. See my last message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from what @Kasra suggested the other slower part in your code is deletion of item at 0th index, for [lists it's `O(N)` operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list). A better data-structure for this is [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which allows fast insertion and deletion on either end.

Comment: Deleting item at index 0, will be very fast I guess.

Comment: So... if I'm understanding it right, collections are same as lists, and I can use deque method as I would use remove or pop?

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar No, it is not similar to list. They are implemented as doubly-linked list internally, i.e slow indexing. So, If you want to access random indices better convert it to list first.

Answer (score 3):

Your following lines are equal to `cards=range(1,a+1)` :

```
cards = []
for num in xrange(1,a+1):
    cards.append(num)
```

As preceding lines use an extra assignment and `append()` function , So replace all of those lines with following :

```
cards=range(1,a+1)
```

Comment: That did boosted up the speed, thanks! But it's still giving me time out at some testcases.

Comment: @JosephSeungJaeDollar welcome , you can use the Ashwini's suggestion too , that i think is a good recipe !

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you

```
a = input()
cards = range(a, 0, -1)
while len(cards)>1:
    del cards[1::2]
print cards[0]
```

Comment: I think you are skipping the part that you have to put the first card to the very back of the stack every other time... so your code always prints out the very last card.

Comment: The order is kept and every other card is removed. I'm not sure about consecutive runs, but this seems pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an instance of [The Josephus Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), which can be solved as follows:

```
def winner(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    elif not n%2:
        return 2*winner(n/2) - 1
    else:
        return 2*winner(n//2) + 1
```

Now, you can use this solution to solve your particular problem as follows:

```
cards = range(1, a+1)
answer = cards[winner(a)-1]
```